# Creating a scatter plot using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am trying to create a scatter plot using both pandas and matplotlib. My goal is to have certain rows and columns accounted for. There's about 1000 data points however I'm only interested in the range 50 to 81. When I plot out the range 0 to 5 it shows the points but not for the other one. Is there anyway to fix this? The first picture is range 50:81 and the second picture is range 0:5.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jlKGF.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v6sVl.png)

```html
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

testproject = r"C:\Users\223070186\Documents\PleaseWork.xlsx"

var = pd.read_excel(testproject, sheet_name ="Test1")

var = var.head()                                                       


df = pd.DataFrame(var, columns = ["Time", "PM1", "PM3", "AFS"])

df2 = df.iloc[50:81, 0:4]


ax1 = df2.plot(kind = "scatter", x = "Time", y = "PM1", color = "r")
ax2 = df2.plot(kind = "scatter", x="Time", y = "PM3", color = "b", ax =ax1)           #placing arguments to make sure that we are able to plot all three at the same time
ax3 = df2.plot(kind = "scatter", x = "Time", y = "AFS", color = "g", ax = ax2)

plt.xlabel("Time")
plt.ylabel("PM1, PM3, AFS")
plt.title("Time vs PM1, PM3, AFS splits")

plt.show(ax1 == ax2 == ax3)
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You did `var = var.head()`  and used that to create a new dataframe.  Probably there aren't 50 rows in that new dataframe.  Did you check the contents of df2?

Comment: Oh I see what your saying. I just deleted it and now everything is showing. Thank you very much. I'm fairly new to coding so I'm still learning here and there.